# Calculate mean after last time of specific column specification

Tags: r

```
example.df <- data.frame(GY = sample(300:600, 200, replace = T), sacc 
                     = rep("f", each = 100), trial.number = rep(1:2, 
each = 100), stringsAsFactors = F)
example.df$sacc[50:70] <- "s"
example.df$sacc[164:170] <- "s"
```

I have data looking similar to this. I would like to calculate the mean of GY after the last appearance of "s" for all the rest of the values of GY where sacc is f. In this example I could ofcourse just average on index number 71:100, however in the real data this isn't the case.

What I tried after the comment of Ronak (thanks!):

```
library(dplyr)
example.df %>%
   group_by(trial.number) %>%
   summarise(mean_tr = mean(GY[(max(which(sacc == "s")) + 1) : n()])) 
%>%
   data.frame()
```

I cant get it to work. Can someone help me out ? My original data.frame is 70k rows, an consists of a lot of variables. class = data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

As we need to do this by group, we can `split` it on `trial.number` and then apply the same operation to each group.

```
sapply(split(example.df, example.df$trial.number), function(x)
         mean(x$GY[(max(which(x$sacc == "s")) + 1) : nrow(x)]))

#   1        2 
#446.2333 471.7000
```

The same using `dplyr` could be achieved by

```
library(dplyr)
example.df %>%
   group_by(trial.number) %>%
   summarise(mean_tr = mean(GY[(max(which(sacc == "s")) + 1) : n()])) %>%
   data.frame()

# trial.number  mean_tr
#1            1 446.2333
#2            2 471.7000
```

Confirming again,

```
mean(example.df$GY[71:100])
#[1] 446.2333

mean(example.df$GY[171:200])
#[1] 471.7
```

**Original Answer**

We could do

```
mean(example.df$GY[(max(which(example.df$sacc == "s")) + 1) : nrow(example.df)])
#[1] 443.6667
```

Here, we first get all the indices where `sacc` is "s" then take `max` of it to get last occurrence. We get the mean of `GY` values from that index to end of the dataframe (`nrow(example.df)`).

To confirm,

```
mean(example.df$GY[71:100])
#[1] 443.6667
```

Comment: I Should have known. Was trying to do the same with dplyr "last", however this results in a value instead of an index number. Thanks, sorry for the easy one ;)

Comment: I cant get it working in dplyr. What I do to have similar data.frames as my example.df is group_by(trial.number) %>% I then summarise(meanGY = mean(GY[max(which(sacc == "s"))+1:nrow(GY))) However, doesnt work :( any suggestion?

Comment: @BartR There is no group in the example you shared. Do you want to take this mean by group ? Can you update the post with the example?

Comment: This indeed works with the example.df. Strangely enough, when I try the exact same with my normal data.frame it results in an Evaluation error: result would be too long a vector and warning: In max(which(sacc == "s)); no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf.. No idea why

Comment: @BartR it looks like your data is very big and it is causing issues to calculate mean.

Comment: Can I send you my data.frame ?

Comment: @BartR That will not help I suppose because it seems like a system dependent issue so even if it works on my system we are not sure if it would work on your system as well. I would suggest break this down into parts (say 10 or 100 `trial.number`) apply the function and then combine them again.